# WP Query by 4 different taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, terms, array, multi-taxonomy-query

I need to make a shortcode that uses the values of four different taxonomies.  I am trying to modify code that I have used to query attachments (in media) based off of multiple taxonomy terms, but what I need is to wp_query based off of 4 (four) taxonomies values.  I realize that I am way off, but perhaps somebody can help put me on the right track.

The Four taxonomies are:

- media_language
- media_document_category
- mp_industry
- mp_product_lines

I want to use a shortcode like :
`[get_media_by_taxes cpt="attachment" media_language="spanish" media_document_category="brochure" mp_industry="food" mp_product_lines="allergens"]`  <--- can I do it this way?

I know the relationship between queries taxonomies is "AND".. below is a copy of the shortcode that pulls by multiple terms.

```php
    function get_media_by_taxes($atts){                             

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cpt'                     => 'attachment',
        'media_language'          => 'english',
        'media_document_category' => 'brochures',
        'mp_industry'               => 'food',
        'mp_product_lines'          => 'allergens', // add default values to these if needed or set defaults as in the example below
    ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' =>  $a['cpt'],
    );
    
    $terms = explode(',', $a['terms']);


    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_language',
            'field'    => $terms,
            'terms'    => ! empty($a['language']) ? $a['language'] : 'english',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_document_category',
            'field'    => $terms,
            'terms'    => ! empty($a['document_category']) ? $a['document_category'] : 'brochures',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mp_industry',
            'field'    => $terms,
            'terms'    => ! empty($a['industry']) ? $a['industry'] : 'food',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mp_product_lines',
            'field'    => $terms,
            'terms'    => ! empty($a['product_lines']) ? $a['product_lines'] : 'allergens',
        ),
    );
    
    $output='<div class="media-attachments-list"><ul>';

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            $output.= '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_link() . '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $output .= '</ul></div>';
    
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

}

      add_shortcode('get_media_by_taxes', 'get_media_by_taxes');
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. If the four taxonomies you mention are the slugs with which the taxonomies are registered, then you need to use those as the `taxonomy` parameters and the terms passed with them as the `terms` parameters for the different `tax_query` arrays.

You'll also need to put the tax parameters to the `shortcode_atts` default array to have them available on the `$a` variable.

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'cpt'               => '',
    'language'          => '',
    'document_category' => '',
    'media_industry'    => '',
    'product_line'      => '', // add default values to these if needed or set defaults as in the example below
), $atts );
```

The different taxonomies could also be optional,

```
if ( $a['language'] ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'media_language',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $a['language'],
    );
}
```

Set default value, if not set with `shortcode_atts()`

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'media_language',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => ! empty($a['language']) ? $a['language'] : 'some-default-term',
    ),
    // more taxonomies...
);
```

I think `'relation' => 'AND'` is the default, so you might not need to explicitly declare it.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for your help.  I edited my post above based off of your feedback (I couldn't figure out a way to do it after your comment).  I am able to get results now, they just aren't correct.  I think I am still doing something incorrectly, I do have defaults added twice, maybe that is why they are including too many results.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Again, very grateful for your help already.

Comment: @panaeleous I'm sorry, I had a small mistake in my example. the `field` parameter in the `tax_query` arrays should be `slug` not `$terms` variable. Maybe fixing this makes the code work.

Comment: thank you Antti, I will try that out.

Comment: That was the answer that worked.  You rock Antti, I really appreciate your help.